# Radio Stations from VLC to internet radio

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to listen in my Internet radio Radio Stations who are played in VLC_media Player. How is the procedure for it?
When possible, in this manner: Station Stream would listen on the Internet Radio thorough
Station URL saved in the Internet Radio. It means without computer?
Thanks!!
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

In VLC there is a one functionality through which you can listen internet radio from VLC:
Open VLC and click on Tools menu go on Plugins and extensions look into Extensions and now go to

[Internet Radio](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/TuneIn+Radio?content=152788)

You can have it on above link or if it is not as per your requirements just go below may be help you out

[Plugins and Extensions](http://addons.videolan.org/)